How to obtain TeX Live 2007 for Linux?
The furthest I got was the Web site http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2007/acquire.html, from which, however, the relevant links seem to be either gone or point to newer TeX Live versions. (No, TeX Live 2008 or newer is NOT an option for me in this specific question. (Yes, I tried.))

Did you try the other links/mirrors in https://tug.org/historic/ ?

@Skillmon These are advertised as mirrors, so, by the definition of the word mirror, I ignored them. However, as you mention them, I'll try …

Not required in the question, but I’m intrigued as to why you need TL’07!

@Skillmon A mirror seems to do the job. The installation succeeds (but the actual compilation of LaTeX sources fails :-().

@JosephWright pstricks changed in an incompatible way shortly before the final TL 2008.

its likely to be easier to just fix the incompatibility in pst than have to install such an old system.

I agree with what @DavidCarlisle says but did you consider using the TeX Live Subversion server to find just the relevant PSTricks files?

@JosephWright No, I have not. In the end, it was easier to install TL 2007, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716605 .

@JosephWright Blaming PStricks is just a guess; the problem might also lie in pdfLaTeXk or some other packages or a combination of them; cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716608 .

Something seems to be off with that specific mirror, it looks like everything is there (e.g. https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2007/texlive2007-inst-20070212.iso) but it's not serving the file list at http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2007/ while https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2007/ does (alongside the contents of acquire.html).
Noting the footer of http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2007/ currently reads
$Date: 2008/08/15 00:52:35 $; [an error occurred while processing this directive]

I guess something is going wrong generating the file list and the mirror is just serving up the nearest index.html as a result.  1999, 2000, 2005 seem to be similarly affected.

The so-called mirrorrs are not fully identical from a public user's view at least as of 2024-04-27. In https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2007 we see https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2007/texlive2007-live-20070212.iso.bz2 and https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2007/texlive2007-inst-20070212.iso .
