Installation of TeX Live 2007 ends up with error messages, saying it fails to build some formats
Upon installing TeX Live 2007 from https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2007/texlive2007-live-20070212.iso.bz2 on Debian 12 in a local user's home directory, we get a bunch of error messages concerning specific formats. After installation and setting the environment variables properly, running fmtutil-sys --all prints lots of stuff and finishes with
###############################################################################
fmtutil: Error! Not all formats have been built successfully.
Visit the log files in directory
  /home/username/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-var/web2c
for details.
###############################################################################

This is a summary of all `failed' messages and warnings:
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=latex -progname=latex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *latex.ini' possibly failed.
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdflatex -progname=pdflatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdflatex.ini' possibly failed.
`omega -ini  -jobname=lambda -progname=lambda lambda.ini' possibly failed.
`aleph -ini  -jobname=lamed -progname=lamed *lambda.ini' possibly failed.
`xetex -ini  -jobname=xelatex -progname=xelatex -etex xelatex.ini' failed
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=platex -progname=platex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *platex.ini' possibly failed.
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdfplatex -progname=pdfplatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfplatex.ini' possibly failed.
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=cslatex -progname=cslatex -etex -translate-file=cp227.tcx cslatex.ini' failed
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdfcslatex -progname=pdfcslatex -etex -translate-file=cp227.tcx cslatex.ini' failed
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=mllatex -progname=mllatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx -mltex mllatex.ini' failed

Alright, I thought, let's look into the logs:
username@hostname:~/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-var/web2c$ $ grep -ir -B12 error
grep: metafont/mf.base: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: tex/tex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: metapost/metafun.mem: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: metapost/mpost.mem: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
--
pdftex/pdflatex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/pdflatex.log-! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
pdftex/pdflatex.log-! That is more than five years old.
pdftex/pdflatex.log-!
pdftex/pdflatex.log-! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format
pdftex/pdflatex.log-! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
pdftex/pdflatex.log-! before continuing to build LaTeX.
pdftex/pdflatex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/pdflatex.log-
pdftex/pdflatex.log-! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
pdftex/pdflatex.log-l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
pdftex/pdflatex.log-                                                  
pdftex/pdflatex.log:To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.
grep: pdftex/pdfcsplain.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/texsis.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/etex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/cont-en.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/pdfetex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/platex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/mex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/pdfplatex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/latex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/pdfjadetex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/jadetex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
--
pdftex/platex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/platex.log-! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
pdftex/platex.log-! That is more than five years old.
pdftex/platex.log-!
pdftex/platex.log-! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format
pdftex/platex.log-! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
pdftex/platex.log-! before continuing to build LaTeX.
pdftex/platex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/platex.log-
pdftex/platex.log-! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
pdftex/platex.log-l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
pdftex/platex.log-                                                  
pdftex/platex.log:To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.
grep: pdftex/pdftex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/amstex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/pdflatex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/physe.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
--
pdftex/latex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/latex.log-! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
pdftex/latex.log-! That is more than five years old.
pdftex/latex.log-!
pdftex/latex.log-! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format
pdftex/latex.log-! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
pdftex/latex.log-! before continuing to build LaTeX.
pdftex/latex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/latex.log-
pdftex/latex.log-! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
pdftex/latex.log-l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
pdftex/latex.log-                                                  
pdftex/latex.log:To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.
grep: pdftex/pdfxmltex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/phyzzx.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
--
pdftex/texsis.log-\@saveVsize=\dimen33
pdftex/texsis.log-\s@veskip=\skip26
pdftex/texsis.log-\doublecolskip=\skip27
pdftex/texsis.log-\@leftpluscenter=\dimen34
pdftex/texsis.log-\partialpage=\box19
pdftex/texsis.log-\botins=\insert252
pdftex/texsis.log-\NWins=\insert251
pdftex/texsis.log-\SWins=\insert250
pdftex/texsis.log-\NEins=\insert249
pdftex/texsis.log-\SEins=\insert248
pdftex/texsis.log-\LFins=\insert247
pdftex/texsis.log-\RFins=\insert246
pdftex/texsis.log:\@balncErrormsg=\toks15
grep: pdftex/csplain.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/xmltex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/pdfmex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/utf8mex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/mltex.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
grep: pdftex/mptopdf.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
--
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-! That is more than five years old.
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-!
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-! before continuing to build LaTeX.
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
pdftex/pdfplatex.log-                                                  
pdftex/pdfplatex.log:To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.
grep: pdftex/eplain.fmt: Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei
--
aleph/lamed.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
aleph/lamed.log-! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
aleph/lamed.log-! That is more than five years old.
aleph/lamed.log-!
aleph/lamed.log-! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format
aleph/lamed.log-! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
aleph/lamed.log-! before continuing to build LaTeX.
aleph/lamed.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
aleph/lamed.log-
aleph/lamed.log-! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
aleph/lamed.log-l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
aleph/lamed.log-                                                  
aleph/lamed.log:To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.
--
omega/lambda.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
omega/lambda.log-! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file
omega/lambda.log-! That is more than five years old.
omega/lambda.log-!
omega/lambda.log-! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format
omega/lambda.log-! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files
omega/lambda.log-! before continuing to build LaTeX.
omega/lambda.log-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
omega/lambda.log-
omega/lambda.log-! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.
omega/lambda.log-l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}
omega/lambda.log-                                                  
omega/lambda.log:To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources.

These parts of the logs are unenlightening.
(1) Are the original warnings/errors real? (xelatex fails to run for my input sources, but it shouldn't mean much because my input might be wrong with respect to that old xelatex.) If they are real, how to repair? Upgrading to TeX Live 2008 is not an option in this question, but downgrading (or setting some flags or terminal encodings) could be (if it only helps).
(2) Anything to get worried about if we run only latex and pdflatex on files encoded in latin1 and UTF8?

even if you only use pdflatex you need to worry about pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdflatex -progname=pdflatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdflatex.ini' possibly failed.  but you have given no information for anyone to debug. that isn't an error message that is just the final summary, you may not have built pdflatex at all or it may have been some minor thing or ...

@DavidCarlisle Thank you! There are many logs. Which ones to look into? I grepped for "error" in the directory stated, but the result was unenlightening.

oh ok so all latex formats will error on building but work fine.

@DavidCarlisle How to test? E.g., any input document that should get processed properly by the old xelatex? Or anything depending on cp227.tcx (Codepage 227 ???)?

if that's the only error in the pdflatex.log then the format is fine, it's just telling you what you already knew that you are building an old latex. As I commented elsewhere I suspect it's all effort in the wrong direction and you should put the effort in to processing the document with a current system, but anyway that install looks fine.

in particular now you have tl2007 installed what happens if you simply copy the old pstricks and use it with the current system

@DavidCarlisle egrep -i "warn|err|miss|fail|undefined|not found|unknown" ~/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log yields only To avoid this error message, obtain new LaTeX sources., so I suspect no other errors. As for copying the old pstricks, would putting the contents of ~/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks into the working directory with the LaTeX document suffice? I'm still unsure whether pstricks is the culprit for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716608, and even if so, whether the error is in the old or in the new pstricks .

For a long while (but not current releases) the latex format would give an error while building the .fmt file if the souce file was more than a certain age this was to encourage people to update and not just stick with some early pre-release of latex2e.
So unless you fake the system clock, or modify the texlive2007 sources to omit this check, then making any latex format (so latex, pdflatex, lualatex, ...) will give the error shown. As the installer scrolls past the error the actual formats still get built but the initex run will have a non zero exit code and so at the end the summary will warn possibly failed.
So assuming you really need to build TeXLive 2007 (and from your other questions that is far from clear) these warnings are expected: they are just warning you that you are using old sources.

Thanks! Sometimes Unix commands are chained in the form, say, cmd1 && cmd2: here, if cmd1 returns an error code(i.e., nonzero), cmd2 is not executed. I have no idea whether this might have happened somewhere inside the installation scripts.
