`! Dimension too large.` after switching from TeX Live 2007 to TeX Live 2008
Running latex followed by dvips in the official TeX Live 2007 (obtained from https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2007/texlive2007-live-20070212.iso.bz2) on
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=.1,yunit=.00001}%
\begin{pspicture}(-10,-40000)(110,330000)
\psaxes[Dy=25000,dy=.4cm,dx=1cm,Dx=10,Ox=0,Oy=0]{->}(0,0)(100,300000)
\rput(103,-20000){foo}
\rput(-5,310000){bar}
\pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,.02)(20,.67)(30,4.78)(40,19.71)(50,59.53)(60,147.31)(70,314.20)(80,607.08)(90,1088.29)(100,1833.74)
\rput(103,1840){A}
\pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,.24)(20,6.52)(30,47.88)(40,198.09)(50,596.20)(60,1466.27)(70,3142.41)(80,6088)(90,10959.65)(100,18576.06)
\rput(103,18570){B}
\pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,.78)(20,21.5)(30,157.57)(40,665.55)(50,1984.13)(60,4881.96)(70,10556.7)(80,20454.83)(90,36712.41)(100,62259.38)
\rput(103,62259.38){C}
\pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,1.85)(20,51.32)(30,379.75)(40,1571.17)(50,4734.92)(60,11749.31)(70,25168.6)(80,48951.76)(90,88900.24)(100,150121.99)
\rput(103,150121.99){D}
\pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,3.58)(20,100.89)(30,746.43)(40,3096.72)(50,9330.72)(60,23048.21)(70,49673.34)(80,96549.38)(90,173745.94)(100,296470.03)
\rput(103,296470.03){E}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

yields a nice graph:

However, the compilation fails in the official TeX Live 2008 (installed from http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2008/tlnet):
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.8 \rput
         (103,-20000){foo}
?

The diff of the logs shows a switch from
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
Babel <v3.8h>
Package: pstricks 2006/08/10 v0.32 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
`PSTricks' v1.15  <2006/12/22> (tvz)
File: pstricks.tex 2006/12/22 v1.15 `PSTricks' (tvz)
pst-plot.tex  v97 patch 2, 1999/12/12
File: pst-plot.tex 2004/05/18 1.41 `pst-plot' (tvz)

in TeX Live 2007 to
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)
Babel <v3.8l>
Package: pstricks 2008/11/26 v0.40 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
`PSTricks' v1.27  <2009/01/25> (tvz)
File: pstricks.tex 2009/01/25 v1.27 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex v1.03, 2008/11/24
File: pst-plot.tex 2008/11/24 1.03 `pst-plot' (tvz)

in TeX Live 2008.
For both years, we have LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>, Package: pst-plot 2004/07/15 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex, and the advertised versions of the remaining classes and packages mentioned in the log: article v1.4f, size10.clo v1.4f, xcolor v2.11, color v1.5, dvips.def v3.0i, and multido v1.41.
Which changes in which part (pdfTeXk, PSTricks, pst-plot, … or some combination of parts of TeX Live) caused the error message and why? Or was there a hidden error (say, an overflow, an underflow, or a drastic loss of precision) in TeX Live 2007 that finally got revealed in TeX Live 2008, as it should?
We don't have the original ground data any longer, so redrawing our graph from scratch will not work. How to transform/scale the numbers in the LaTeX document to create exactly the same graph (in case there was no hidden error in TeX Live 2007) or the probably intended graph (in case there was a hidden error in TeX Live 2007) in a way that would also work with TeX Live 2008 (and, hopefully, more modern TeX Lives)?
If anyone has a link to a later TeX Live 2007 or an earlier TeX Live 2008 (than the official ones), please yell: then I could probably narrow down the range of packages and files to compare.
Following the ideas of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716613 (Herbert?), we tried to multiply yunit by 100 from the very beginning, but the results look surprising: running latex followed by dvips from TeX Live 2009 (because TeX Live 2008 doesn't have ylabelFactor) just on the axes
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=.1,yunit=.001}%
\begin{pspicture}(-10,-400)(110,3300)
  \psaxes[Dy=250,dy=.4cm,dx=1cm,Dx=10,Ox=0,Oy=0,ylabelFactor=00%%% From TeX Live 2009 onward
  ]{->}(0,0)(100,3000)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

yields a different maximal value on the vertical axis (175000 instead of 250000):

Why?

Use it this way. Only the coordinates for the pspicture environment changes::
%\DocumentMetadata{}%% Only if running it with lualatex TL 2020 at least!!
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=.1,yunit=.02}%%%
\begin{pspicture}(-10,-40)(110,330)%%%
    \psaxes[Dy=25,dy=.5cm,dx=1cm,Dx=10,Ox=0,Oy=0,ylabelFactor=\cdot10^3]{->}(0,0)(100,300)%%%
    \psset{yunit=0.001}%%% 
    \rput(103,-20000){foo}
    \rput(-5,310000){bar}
    \pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,.02)(20,.67)(30,4.78)(40,19.71)(50,59.53)(60,147.31)(70,314.20)(80,607.08)(90,1088.29)(100,1833.74)
    \rput(103,1840){A}
    \pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,.24)(20,6.52)(30,47.88)(40,198.09)(50,596.20)(60,1466.27)(70,3142.41)(80,6088)(90,10959.65)(100,18576.06)
    \rput(103,18570){B}
    \pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,.78)(20,21.5)(30,157.57)(40,665.55)(50,1984.13)(60,4881.96)(70,10556.7)(80,20454.83)(90,36712.41)(100,62259.38)
    \rput(103,62259.38){C}
    \pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,1.85)(20,51.32)(30,379.75)(40,1571.17)(50,4734.92)(60,11749.31)(70,25168.6)(80,48951.76)(90,88900.24)(100,150121.99)
    \rput(103,150121.99){D}
    \pscurve{-}(1,0)(10,3.58)(20,100.89)(30,746.43)(40,3096.72)(50,9330.72)(60,23048.21)(70,49673.34)(80,96549.38)(90,173745.94)(100,296470.03)
    \rput(103,296470.03){E}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}



Thank you! In the labels of the vertical axis, how to get “000”, as in the original, instead of “ · 10³”?

ylabelFactor=1000

In TeX Live 2008, I get ! Graphics parameter \ylabelFactor' not defined..`. Morever, it seems that in your graph, the vertical labels are spread further apart (and probably the vertical size of the whole picture is larger). We need to embed this graph into a (non-MWE) paper. To ensure that the page breaks are at the same positions, we need the re-drawn graph to occupy the same vertical space as the old one (at least if there was no hidden error in TL 2007).

I See, TL2008 is really really old ... However, it should work with installing PSTricks and pst-plot from https://mirror.ctan.org.   But I didn't test it

Concerning your “the coordinates for the pspicture environment changes”: no, in addition to changing the coordinates in \begin{pspicture}(…)(…), you made changes in yunit=… before \begin{pspicture}, you made changes in \psaxes…, and you made changes in yunit=… after \begin{pspicture}(…)(…). Could we kindly ask you to explain what you've done?

@AlMa1r those changes are all the same thing, the original had a dangerously small y axis scale of .00001 which meant using dangerously large numbers when refering to y coordinates 330000  something in the arithmetic now makes a calculation overflow, so the post here uses a more reasonable scale factor of .02 (I'd have expected .01 but...) and then use correspondingly smaller numbers when using y coordinates 330

@DavidCarlisle Could there be a silent overflow already when using TeX Live 2007?

quite possibly, or maybe an internal calculation happens in a different order and a value now gets larger, I really don't know and I certainly wouldn't install tl 2007 to find out. I would just use a texlive 2024 make the plot look as good as you wish and then put it in a tex box of a forced size so that it is the same size as your old picture. not changing page breaking is the easy part

@DavidCarlisle The point is that if there is a silent overflow in TeX Live 2007, then it's wrong to try to have the graph look similar in TL 2008, and if there is no silent overflow in TL 2007, then it's on the contrary necessary to have the graph in TL 2008 look similar to the one in TL 2007.

shrug it's just a very generic graph, the differences between the images shown in the question and this answer don't change the data shown, just some small changes in y axis scaling so for example the A and B are not touching, but scaling a graph doesn't change anything about the data it's showing.

The change of dy from .4cm to .5cm in \psaxes[…] is unmotivated: yunit and the coordinates are scaled by a power of 10, so we should expect no change at all. But the output does change for no good reason if dy stays at .4cm.
